# How to install hpn ssh on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, 20.04

I want to transfer files via ssh, but it's slow. I've read [hpn ssh](https://www.psc.edu/hpn-ssh) can speed up ssh. However, I don't know how to install it on Ubuntu 20.04. I just find nothing about this subject on the internet!!!!

Please guide me

Comment: Are you asking how to install a deb package that you downloaded from a random internet site? Use apt or Ubuntu Software. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: If you try SMB/CIFS you will know what is slow. About compiling HPN-SSH - try to follow [ArchLinux AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=openssh-hpn).

Comment: @user535733 I wrote I found nothing about it and ubuntu, no `apt`, no `deb package`... I just found an`rpm` package which I guess isn't for Ubuntu

Comment: @N0rbert could you please say what should I do with that file? should I download it and run it? I cloned the git address and the file named `PKGBUILD` was also copied, I tried to run it in terminal, with `sudo ./PKGBUILD` it gives a syntax error at the first line, and without `sudo` it just finishes without any message!

Comment: You have to read this file and execute some commands from it get HPN-SSH compiled and installed. Other possibility is to try deb-packages from https://sourceforge.net/projects/hpnssh/files/Debian%20Packages/ .

Comment: @N0rbert what type of file is it? I mean the same PKGBUILD you refered? can't it be run automatically and does what is nessesarry? Why should I run the instructions, in which language are they? How can I for example run a function called `build()` in that file? Sorry, if I sound novice, but I expected one command or one click solution! I just wonder why there is so few support of this `hpn` stuff

Comment: @N0rbert for the link on `sourceforge.net` I read this: "We now have binaries for HPN-SSH. Currently just rpms but you'll find them under the RPMS folder. Debian packages are coming soon. Patches, for those that like to roll their own, are now under Patches." what does it mean

Comment: The problem here is that HPN-SSH compile recipe exists only for ArchLinux. The PKGBUILD file describe how ArchLinux compile source code of the application and install it. In some cases these files are simple and we can execute commands from `build` function. About sourceforge I do not really know what is posted here. I would recommend to install deb-package for test on VM with your current Ubuntu version. Or simpler - use ordinary SSH which is proven to be stable and fast enough for years. Its speed is near full bandwidth of LAN while doing file-transfer via SSHfs.

Comment: @N0rbert thank you for clarification and guides

Answer (score 3):

From the comments - really you have two possible methods of HPN-SSH installation:

- Follow the recipe for compilation and installation of HPN-SSH may be done by following steps from [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=openssh-hpn).
- Use pre-compiled binaries at https://sourceforge.net/projects/hpnssh/files/Debian%20Packages/ . You may want to test them on VM with your current Ubuntu version.

But I do not recommend to do so because of the fact that the ordinary SSH is proven to be stable and fast enough for years. Its speed is near full bandwidth of LAN while doing file-transfer via SSHfs. The roots of HPN-SSH are in supercomputing, but I do not think that you owning any of it. So speed of ordinary SSH would be enough. If you want to check what is really slow - try SMB/CIFS (Windows file-sharing) to compare.

Comment: the sourceforge is an rpm package... I just extracted the files and manually copied them over my current files (e.g `/usr/bin/ssh`) I don't know if it was what I must do... Anyways the file transfer speed didn't change... I wrote my exact problem in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255932/why-file-transfer-over-ssh-drops

Comment: @Ahmad - Are you updating both client and server?  It looks like that's necessary from the README.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone else is looking for an answer... So I'm the guy that developed HPN-SSH. HPN-SSH is a series of patches against OpenSSH. It's 100% compatible with OpenSSH because, well, it is OpenSSH with some added features. While these features were developed with high performance networking in mind it was started back when 1Gb connections were still the domain of major research centers. The main thing that HPN-SSH does is let the internal OpenSSH receive buffers be aware of the autotuning TCP receive buffers. This can lead to higher performance especially in if the path has a high BDP. You can read more about it at http://hpnssh.org.

We do have a number of prebuilt packages for Debian, Fedora, CentOS, and so forth. You can get those from https://sourceforge.net/projects/hpnssh. You can also get the full git repo from https://github.com/rapier1/openssh-portable. If you really want you can also join the mailing list at hpnssh-community@psc.edu