# Why file transfer over ssh drops

Tags: networking, ssh, 20.04

I'm trying to trasfer a file over ssh. The file is `78M` and I connected to the server via VPN. I ran the following command to transfer the file:

```
sshpass -p "xxx" rsync -avz --progress -e ssh -c "x.zip"  xxx@17x.1x.1xx.8:/home/xxx/
```

At the first seconds the rate is about 2.5M/s and 25% of the file is copied but fastly it drops to about 100K/s and continues uploading...

I want to know if that's the normal behavior or something is wrong? Is it possible to transfer file in Megabytes per seconds?

I also tried with `scp`. It doesn't show the speed, but it seems the speed is about the same...

I even got binaries of a patch for ssh named `ssh hpn` and replaced `usr\bin\ssh` with them, but the result is the same...